# Custom HTML Email Template Formatting issues

Tags: email-template

I am creating a new email template. I am using the Custom (without using Letterhead) option. I have been building the HTML in NOTEPAD++ as a basic HTML editor. The template includes 2 tables with rows and columns, and shading for the rows. From NOTEPAD++ I can preview in Chrome, FF, and IE. All look great. When I preview in SF (HTML Preview), it looks great.  When I execute the Send Test and Verify Merge Fields, to my GMAIL address, I get the right data, and I can see the table, but most of my table formatting is gone (Shading, mostly). This is true for Chrome, FF and IE. In the Outlook 2010 desktop client, some of the table formatting is still there but not all.

I have tried copying the HTML from NOTEPAD++ to Notepad and then to SF, but the result is the same. Is there anyway to make sure I keep my formatting? I am no expert in HTML, and I relied heavily on this website for examples of how to build my HTML code. http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following link to verify that the style you have used is supported or not.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Email client don;t support all css features so you will have to be careful about the css you are using to show the formatting.

Given link has details of all supported tags in Email body.